# How to implement the following Alloy model in Alloy API?

Tags: alloy

I have the following Alloy model and I'm not sure how to convert it to the Alloy Java API.

```
sig A {
  B: Int
}
```

I know we can use `A.addField("B", Expr)` to add the attribute, but what should I put in the `Expr` parameter to make it represents `Int`s?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is much easier to parse the entire Alloy model from string instead of creating AST manually.  See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17113035/1485337) for an example.  That example uses

```
CompUtil.parseEverything_fromFile(..., <file_name>)
```

but you can replace that with

```
CompUtil.parseOneModule_fromString("sig A{ B: Int}")
```

to parse directly from string (note that the return type in the latter case is `List<Command>`, and not `CompModule` like in the linked example, but that shouldn't be a problem for you).